# showing Time from database in Timepicker directive Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using [timepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker)
there is an error to getting data from database : here is what should it be :

```
VisitDate: "2015-05-21T17:30:00"
```

here is what i get :

```
21:00  

                

<timepicker ng-model="visitPlaceViewModel.VisitDate" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian" class="timePicker"></timepicker>
```

**Update** :
It works on firefox but not in chrome

Answer (score 0):

in my case I need to appending the timezone offset `+08:00` to meet the time that I want.

```
$scope.VisitDate=new Date("2015-05-21T17:30:00+08:00");
```